# Creating a confusion matrix in python

Tags: python, pandas

I am having issues creating a confusion matrix in python. I currently have the following csv file with a table organized in two columns as presented:

```
----------
Letter | Code

A   |        ["13.45", "16.59", "12.28"] 

B   |        ["13.45", "18.20"]

C   |        ["13.45", "18.20", "19.30"]
```

My goal is to generate 3 extra columns with the heading `A`, `B` and `C` where their intersection with the other would be the percentage of codes that column letter has in common with that row letter. For column `"A"` for example would be:

```
1

1/3

1/3
```

For column `B`:

```
1/2

1

1
```

and so on. I am not aware if this is possible with pandas or other package but if anyone could help me I would be extremely glad. Please understand that I have low literacy regarding python ( and sorry for the awful formatting of my problem). Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

You could use `apply` and `set` `intersection`

For individual column

```
In [607]: A = df.query('letter == "A"').code.item()

In [608]: df.code.apply(lambda x: len(set(x).intersection(A))) / len(A)
Out[608]:
0    1.000000
1    0.333333
2    0.333333
Name: code, dtype: float64

In [609]: B = df.query('letter == "B"').code.item()

In [610]: df.code.apply(lambda x: len(set(x).intersection(B))) / len(B)
Out[610]:
0    0.5
1    1.0
2    1.0
Name: code, dtype: float64

In [611]: A
Out[611]: ['13.45', '16.59', '12.28']

In [612]: B
Out[612]: ['13.45', '18.20']
```

And, if you want all the rows at once

```
In [628]: pd.DataFrame(
          {r['letter'] : df.code.apply(lambda x: 
           len(set(x).intersection(r['code']))) / len(r['code']) 
           for i, r in df.iterrows()})
Out[628]:
          A    B         C
0  1.000000  0.5  0.333333
1  0.333333  1.0  0.666667
2  0.333333  1.0  1.000000
```

Join to original dataframe

```
In [629]: pd.DataFrame(
          {r['letter'] : df.code.apply(lambda x: 
           len(set(x).intersection(r['code']))) / len(r['code']) 
           for i, r in df.iterrows()}).join(df)
Out[629]:
          A    B         C letter                   code
0  1.000000  0.5  0.333333      A  [13.45, 16.59, 12.28]
1  0.333333  1.0  0.666667      B         [13.45, 18.20]
2  0.333333  1.0  1.000000      C  [13.45, 18.20, 19.30]
```

Comment: Hey John, thank you for the reply. Is there any way to make the calculation of the number of codes on each column and for each row automatic? I only provided the example of 3 letters but I actually have thousands and I would like to generate a new column for each letter and respective calculation, of the number of codes, for each row

Comment: Oh sorry, didn't see the follow up. Yes this is exactly what I want to achieve! Is it possible nonetheless to do this to string data? Because the codes sometimes are like this "13.45.56" or "13333.33-45.3312".

Comment: Yes, try it on your data.

Comment: I am trying to use the last command (the one that says "Join to original dataframe") However I only get an error saying: TypeError: 'float' object is not iterable. :(

Comment: Nevermind John I've managed to make it work with some tweaks, thank you so much :)

Comment: It seems however not to give suitable percentages. Using the example above: http://puu.sh/xefUg/ec7d67aaad.png